# Swipe leads Unfortunately app has stopped android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

In my app I am using View Pager and Action bar Tabs. There are three fragments, when I swipe forward it loads the fragments correctly,and when I swipe backwards it doesn't loads the fragment.
It shows like, Unfortunately the app has stopped.

Fragment 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fram_map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_draw_State"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Free Draw" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/btn_erase_State"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
         android:text="Free Erase" />
     <Button
         android:id="@+id/btn_location_State"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
         android:text="Choose Current Location" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/btn_check_location"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
         android:text="Check Status of user" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment 2: This xml is for the fragment 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ff8400" >

<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Design Games Screen"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Fragment: This contain the fragment 3 xml coding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#17df0d"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Design Movies Screen"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="49dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="91dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Logcat:

```
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047): Process: com.safetravelling.norton, PID: 10047
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at com.safetravelling.norton.DrawPathFragment.onCreateView(DrawPathFragment.java:57)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1280)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:672)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:550)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:509)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:490)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at com.safetravelling.norton.MainActivity.onTabSelected(MainActivity.java:75)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at com.android.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.selectTab(WindowDecorActionBar.java:624)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at com.android.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar$TabImpl.select(WindowDecorActionBar.java:1210)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:546)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #6: Duplicate id 0x7f0b0019, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    05-06 09:46:21.451: E/AndroidRuntime(10047):    ... 29 more
```

Comment: The fragment's `onCreateView()` code and its XML layout are needed.

Comment: yes i added the xml coding pls see...

Comment: Open `R.java`, find resource with ID `0x7f0b0019`, and change its name in XML file to something more unique _(do not manually edit `R.java`)_. I am guessing you are using the same ID name as in the GMS.

Comment: No @ozbek. i tried whatever u said. same error i getting... pls check any other mistake i made...

Comment: @Android777 can you pls figure out the error... i tried i cant find...

Comment: Right now I see 3 XML layouts and have no idea which one of them is the one your logcat is talking about. And I cannot see any `onCreateView()` for the *problem* fragment (not for all your fragments).